# How to force django rest framework api_view to use a specific parser?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing an API for a legacy client which is not under my control.

The request is a POST which body is a JSON string.

Depending on the situation, there is no content type header, or the content type header is wrong.

I implemented the API. It's working fine with a CURL client that adds the `application/json` content type. But it throws a 415 error when the content type is not provided. The problem is that I can't have the client add the correct content type.

How to force the view wrapped by `@api_view(['POST'])` to use a `JSONParser` no matter the headers of the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ditch the standard content negotiation and use something simpler, you can use a custom content negotiation class.  The example [given in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation#example) fits your needs.

```
class IgnoreClientContentNegotiation(BaseContentNegotiation):
    def select_parser(self, request, parsers):
        """
        Select the first parser in the `.parser_classes` list.
        """
        return parsers[0]
```

You'll also want to adjust your settings, to use your custom class...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_CONTENT_NEGOTIATION_CLASS':
        'myapp.negotiation.IgnoreClientContentNegotiation',
}
```